# PHP file_put_contents works with file, no file gets "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, fwrite

The PHP `file_put_contents` function works perfectly fine when the file exists. If the file does not exist I receive the error "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

```
 $file = '../templates/stuff.xml';
 if (!file_exists($file)) {$file = '../'.$file;}
 $var['xhtml'] = $_POST['post_xhtml'];
 $file_contents = serialize($var);
 file_put_contents($file,$file_contents);
```

I tried the same thing with `fopen` and `fwrite` using the correct flags (`w`, `w+` and tried the others) yet still had the same problem: if the file already existed it worked just fine, otherwise it would give me the same error message.

I know the file path is correct. I'm using Windows 7 for local development.

Comment: When the file doesn't exist, you are prepending `../` to the path.  Does *that* file exist?  Is that file writable?  Does PHP have permission to access that folder?  Are you sure the folder `../../templates` exists?

Comment: Ha, worked...not sure why, I should have checked for the **directory** actually. Post it as an answer so I can officially accept it please.

Answer (score 1):

When the file doesn't exist, you are prepending `../` to the path, thus you are trying to write to:

```
../../templates/stuff.xml
```

Are you sure that the folder `../../templates` exists (and that PHP can write to it)?

Before you write to a file, you need to check that the folder exists.  Try using [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/is_dir):

```
if(is_dir(dirname($file))){
    file_put_contents($file, $file_contents);
}
```

Comment: You may consider using a full path. Also there is a file_exists() function that you can use in an "if" condition before you try to get it.